# Creating new AD B2C user via Microsoft Graph API

Tags: .net, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c

I've decided on using the `Microsoft.Graph` .NET SDK instead of using the old Azure Graph API with manual HTTP requests.

The problem is that when I try to create a new user with some email, e.g. areller@gmail.com

```
var req = _client.Users.Request();
var userRes = req.AddAsync(new User()
{
    AccountEnabled = true,
    DisplayName = user.Email,
    MailNickname = user.GivenName,
    GivenName = user.GivenName,
    Surname = user.SurName,
    UserPrincipalName = user.Email,
    PasswordProfile = new PasswordProfile()
    {
        Password = user.Password,
        ForceChangePasswordNextSignIn = true
    },
    PasswordPolicies = "DisablePasswordExpiration, DisableStrongPassword",
    Country = user.Country,
    City = user.City,
    PostalCode = user.ZipCode
}).Result;
```

I get an exception that says 'Property userPrincipalName is invalid'
[image]

I'm only able to create the user when I use an email with the tenant as a domain, e.g. `areller@mytenant.onmicrosoft.com`
But this is not what I need.
I need to be able to create actual external users programaticaly.

With Azure Graph API it works
Is there a way to make it work with the Microsoft Graph API?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Currently, you can't use Microsoft Graph to create users in an Azure AD B2C tenant, because it doesn't support a few of the user properties (including the **creationType** and **signInNames** properties) that are used by Azure AD B2C.

You must [use Azure AD Graph for this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/ad/graph/api/users-operations#CreateLocalAccountUser).

Note: When you create users in an Azure AD B2C tenant be setting the **creationType** property to `LocalAccount`, then the **userPrincipalName** property doesn't have to be set, because it's the **signInNames** property that contains the e-mail address of the external user.

Comment: That's what i thought, but i couldn't find any confirmation for it. Do you know if there are a .NET sdk for azure graph api?

Comment: Hi @areller. See [the .NET Client Library for Microsoft Azure Active Directory Graph API](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient).

Comment: Github sample - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-graph-dotnet

Answer (score 12):

According to [Azure Samples help page](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-dotnetcore-b2c-account-management)
you can now use Microsoft Graph to create a new user for Azure AD B2C. See [the code sample here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-dotnetcore-b2c-account-management/blob/master/src/Services/UserService.cs).

```
var result = await graphClient.Users
            .Request()
            .AddAsync(new User
            {
                GivenName = "Casey",
                Surname = "Jensen",
                DisplayName = "Casey Jensen",
                Identities = new List<ObjectIdentity>
                {
                    new ObjectIdentity()
                    {
                        SignInType = "emailAddress",
                        Issuer = tenantId,
                        IssuerAssignedId = "casey.jensen@example.com"
                    }
                },
                PasswordProfile = new PasswordProfile()
                {
                    Password = Helpers.PasswordHelper.GenerateNewPassword(4, 8, 4)
                },
                PasswordPolicies = "DisablePasswordExpiration",
                AdditionalData = extensionInstance
            });
```

Comment: Upvoted, while I was trying to do this via Java, there was enough information here to help me add a (federated?) user.  Thanks

Comment: This example is going to give you the error "Issuer should match tenants domainName for non federated identity."  sense you domain is not "example.com"